# eclipse CDT - Cannot open .gcda files

Tags: eclipse, cygwin, code-coverage, eclipse-cdt, gcov

I am developing a coverage data tool in eclipse cdt. I used gcov and build and execute my C program to generate .gcda and .gcno files.

When double click on .gcda file to see the coverage data, below error message displays.

> An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
>   org.eclipse.linuxtools.binutils.utils.STSymbolManager.demangle(Lorg/eclipse/cdt/core/IBinaryParser$IBinaryObject;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IProject;)Ljava/lang/String;

But I already downloaded and save **org.eclipse.linuxtools.binutils_4.0.0.201209191645.jar** into ***plugins*** directory.

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after doing some further reasearch I was able to get rid of this problem.

After completing following requirements, I was able to open & view coverage details in .gcda files.

- Eclipse Indigo
- CDT 8.0
- Eclipse   GCov Integration (Incubation) 0.6.0.201202152032 Plugin
- Eclipse   GProf Integration (Incubation) 0.7.0.201202152032 Plugin
- Cygwin
- GNU cygwin binutils (strings.exe,addr2line.exe, c++filt.exe and nm.exe should be there)
- cygwin\bin path should be in the system PATH